# ClassCastException in Keycloak 15

Tags: java, keycloak

We use Keycloak 7.0.1 to authorize users, 2 years ago we migrated from our software to Keycloak, so we use spi, since we have a separate database for clients. Now we want to upgrade to version 15.0.2, but the following error comes out:

```
ERROR [org.keycloak.services.error.KeycloakErrorHandler] (default task-9) Uncaught server error: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.keycloak.models.sessions.infinispan.entities.AuthenticatedClientSessionEntity cannot be cast to org.keycloak.models.sessions.infinispan.entities.UserSessionEntity 
            at org.infinispan.util.concurrent.CompletionStages.join(CompletionStages.java:82) 
            at org.infinispan.stream.impl.AbstractCacheStream.performPublisherOperation(AbstractCacheStream.java:207) 
            at org.infinispan.stream.impl.DistributedCacheStream.collect(DistributedCacheStream.java:285) 
            at org.infinispan.util.AbstractDelegatingCacheStream.collect(AbstractDelegatingCacheStream.java:280) 
            at org.keycloak.models.sessions.infinispan.InfinispanUserSessionProvider.getActiveClientSessionStats(InfinispanUserSessionProvider.java:532) 
            at org.keycloak.services.resources.admin.RealmAdminResource.getClientSessionStats(RealmAdminResource.java:630) 
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) 
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) 
            at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:138) 
            at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.internalInvokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:546) 
            at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTargetAfterFilter(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:435) 
            at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.lambda$invokeOnTarget$0(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:396) 
            at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:358) 
            at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:398) 
            at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:365) 
            at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invokeOnTargetObject(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:150) 
            at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invoke(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:110) 
            at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invokeOnTargetObject(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:141) 
            at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invoke(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:104) 
            at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:440) 
            at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:229) 
            at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:135) 
            at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:358) 
            at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:138) 
            at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:215) 
            at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:245) 
            at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:61) 
            at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56) 
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590) 
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74) 
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129) 
            at org.keycloak.provider.wildfly.WildFlyRequestFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(WildFlyRequestFilter.java:41) 
            at org.keycloak.services.filters.AbstractRequestFilter.filter(AbstractRequestFilter.java:43) 
            at org.keycloak.provider.wildfly.WildFlyRequestFilter.doFilter(WildFlyRequestFilter.java:39) 
            at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61) 
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131) 
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84) 
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62) 
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68) 
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) 
            at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78) 
            at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) 
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68) 
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:117) 
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57) 
            at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) 
            at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46) 
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64) 
            at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60) 
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77) 
            at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50) 
            at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43) 
            at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) 
            at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61) 
            at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) 
            at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68) 
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.SendErrorPageHandler.handleRequest(SendErrorPageHandler.java:52) 
            at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) 
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:269) 
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:78) 
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:133) 
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:130) 
            at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48) 
            at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43) 
            at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105) 
            at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530) 
            at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530) 
            at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530) 
            at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530) 
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:249) 
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:78) 
            at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:99) 
            at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:387) 
            at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:841) 
            at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35) 
            at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990) 
            at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486) 
            at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377) 
            at org.xnio.XnioWorker$WorkerThreadFactory$1$1.run(XnioWorker.java:1280) 
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) 
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.keycloak.models.sessions.infinispan.entities.AuthenticatedClientSessionEntity cannot be cast to org.keycloak.models.sessions.infinispan.entities.UserSessionEntity 
            at org.keycloak.models.sessions.infinispan.stream.UserSessionPredicate.test(UserSessionPredicate.java:129) 
            at org.keycloak.models.sessions.infinispan.stream.UserSessionPredicate.test(UserSessionPredicate.java:37) 
            at io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFilter$FilterSubscriber.tryOnNext(FlowableFilter.java:68) 
            at io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFilter$FilterSubscriber.onNext(FlowableFilter.java:52) 
            at io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableMap$MapConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FlowableMap.java:112) 
            at io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.util.HalfSerializer.onNext(HalfSerializer.java:45) 
            at io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.innerNext(FlowableConcatMap.java:204) 
            at io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableConcatMap$ConcatMapInner.onNext(FlowableConcatMap.java:561) 
            at io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFilter$FilterSubscriber.tryOnNext(FlowableFilter.java:74) 
            at io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFromIterable$IteratorConditionalSubscription.slowPath(FlowableFromIterable.java:380) 
            at io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFromIterable$BaseRangeSubscription.request(FlowableFromIterable.java:131) 
            at io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.subscribers.BasicFuseableSubscriber.request(BasicFuseableSubscriber.java:153) 
            at io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.subscriptions.SubscriptionArbiter.setSubscription(SubscriptionArbiter.java:99) 
            at io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableConcatMap$ConcatMapInner.onSubscribe(FlowableConcatMap.java:554) 
            at io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.subscribers.BasicFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(BasicFuseableSubscriber.java:67) 
            at io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFromIterable.subscribe(FlowableFromIterable.java:66) 
            at io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFromIterable.subscribeActual(FlowableFromIterable.java:47) 
            at io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:15838) 
            at io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFilter.subscribeActual(FlowableFilter.java:37) 
            at io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:15838) 
            at io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:15784) 
            at io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.drain(FlowableConcatMap.java:316) 
            at io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableConcatMap$BaseConcatMapSubscriber.onSubscribe(FlowableConcatMap.java:122) 
            at io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.jdk8.FlowableFromStream.subscribeStream(FlowableFromStream.java:74) 
            at io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.jdk8.FlowableFromStream.subscribeActual(FlowableFromStream.java:45) 
            at io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:15838) 
            at io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:15784) 
            at io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableConcatMap.subscribeActual(FlowableConcatMap.java:64) 
            at io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:15838) 
            at io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableMap.subscribeActual(FlowableMap.java:36) 
            at io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:15838) 
            at io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableFilter.subscribeActual(FlowableFilter.java:37) 
            at io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:15838) 
            at io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableMap.subscribeActual(FlowableMap.java:38) 
            at io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:15838) 
            at io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:15784) 
            at io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.jdk8.FlowableFlatMapStream.subscribeActual(FlowableFlatMapStream.java:75) 
            at io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Flowable.subscribe(Flowable.java:15838) 
            at io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableCollectSingle.subscribeActual(FlowableCollectSingle.java:52) 
            at io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Single.subscribe(Single.java:4813) 
            at io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Single.subscribeWith(Single.java:4863) 
            at io.reactivex.rxjava3.core.Single.toCompletionStage(Single.java:5635) 
            at org.infinispan.reactive.publisher.PublisherReducers$CollectorReducer.apply(PublisherReducers.java:227) 
            at org.infinispan.reactive.publisher.PublisherReducers$CollectorReducer.apply(PublisherReducers.java:216) 
            at org.infinispan.stream.impl.CacheStreamIntermediateReducer.apply(CacheStreamIntermediateReducer.java:41) 
            at org.infinispan.stream.impl.CacheStreamIntermediateReducer.apply(CacheStreamIntermediateReducer.java:26) 
            at org.infinispan.reactive.publisher.impl.NonSegmentedLocalPublisherManagerImpl.exactlyOnceSequential(NonSegmentedLocalPublisherManagerImpl.java:57) 
            at org.infinispan.reactive.publisher.impl.LocalPublisherManagerImpl.exactlyOnce(LocalPublisherManagerImpl.java:436) 
            at org.infinispan.reactive.publisher.impl.LocalPublisherManagerImpl.entryReduction(LocalPublisherManagerImpl.java:160) 
            at org.infinispan.reactive.publisher.impl.ClusterPublisherManagerImpl$EntryComposedType.localInvocation(ClusterPublisherManagerImpl.java:735) 
            at org.infinispan.reactive.publisher.impl.ClusterPublisherManagerImpl.startSegmentPublisher(ClusterPublisherManagerImpl.java:304) 
            at org.infinispan.reactive.publisher.impl.ClusterPublisherManagerImpl.reduction(ClusterPublisherManagerImpl.java:163) 
            at org.infinispan.reactive.publisher.impl.ClusterPublisherManagerImpl.entryReduction(ClusterPublisherManagerImpl.java:144) 
            at org.infinispan.stream.impl.AbstractCacheStream.performPublisherOperation(AbstractCacheStream.java:204) 
            ... 80 more
```

This happens when we try to open the sessions window in the administrative console or when we try to logout our clients. On version 7.0.1. there were no such mistakes.
Has anyone come across a similar one?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you please share the code of your SPI?

Comment: Sorry, I wrote the answer, for some reason it did not save. We found an error, it was a wrong configuration of caches